# C# Console Application after windows log off

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, console-application

How to keep running c# console application after login with its UI (console window) to insert data into SharePoint 2013 list item.

Windows Service & Task Scheduler will not give me UI (Console window) by which i can see the running process.

Happy Coding... :)

Comment: Do you mean, once you lock or log off from your account the console application should be running in window? Correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: Yes, i need that kind of solution... if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you log off, all your Windows are closed (and all corresponding processes are exited). Thats how Windows works. You can´t have a cross-Session-Window. All you could do is lock your pc

Comment: Thanks Leopold, I am aware of this thing but if its possible than i need a solution which works after login with UI to show my process.